# Tricky calculation transformation based on a row sum using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to round values in specific columns according to these rules:

```
if = or > 0.6 round to nearest even number
if < 0.6 round to 0

if and only if the sum of the values does not exceed its total by row rounded to the nearest 
number. If the total is exceeded,
subtract or add this delta to equal the value rounded to the nearest even number.
```

logic:
looking at the first row, the sum of the values = 3.3, and the nearest even number = 4
based on the above rules,

```
if = or > 0.6 round to nearest even number
if < 0.6 round to 0
```

the first row would now be:

```
   location     range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27       
   NY           Lower_ stat AA      2       2       0       2
```

However, the original sum of this row rounded to the nearest even number would be 4.
however, now the sum = 6. So we would need to subtract the delta of 2 from the last value which now would be:

```
 location   range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27       
 NY         Lower_ stat AA      2       2       0       0
```

In this case, we actually add 2, since the sum of this row = 1.1
and the nearest even number would be 2. Number will replace the largest value of the row.

```
 location   range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27   
 NY         Lower_range BB      0.3     0.4     0.2     0.2
```

So this would be:

```
  location          range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27
  NY                Lower_range BB      0       2       0       0
```

**Data**

```
location    range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27       
NY          Lower_ stat AA      1       1.2     0.5     0.6     
NY          Lower_range AA      0.4     1.9     0.4     0.6     
NY          Lower_stat  BB      0.1     0.1     0.1     0.1     
NY          Lower_range BB      0.3     0.4     0.2     0.2




data = {'location': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY'],
        'range': ['Lower_stat', 'Lower_range', 'Lower_stat', 'Lower_range'],
        'role': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
        'Q1 27': [1, 0.4, 0.1, 0.3],
        'Q2 27': [1.2, 1.9, 0.1, 0.4],
        'Q3 27': [0.5, 0.4, 0.1, 0.2],
        'Q4 27': [0.6, 0.6, 0.1, 0.2]}
```

**Desired**

```
location        range       type    Q1 27   Q2 27   Q3 27   Q4 27       
NY              Lower_ stat AA      2       2       0       0       
NY              Lower_range AA      0       2       0       2       
NY              Lower_stat  BB      0       0       0       0       
NY              Lower_range BB      0       2       0       0



data = {'location': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY'],
        'range': ['Lower_stat', 'Lower_range', 'Lower_stat', 'Lower_range'],
        'type': ['AA', 'AA', 'BB', 'BB'],
        'Q1 27': [2, 0, 0, 0],
        'Q2 27': [2, 2, 0, 2],
        'Q3 27': [0, 0, 0, 0],
        'Q4 27': [0, 2, 0, 0]}
```

**Doing**

first part

```
i = df.iloc[:, 2:].astype(int)
df2 = (i+i.mod(2) 
       
       # round to nearest 2
       # add 2 for values between 0.6-1
       
       +2*(df.iloc[:, 2:].ge(0.6)
           &df.iloc[:, 2:].lt(1))
       )
```

second part

```
# create the delta with difference b/w sum of the two DF
df2['delta']=df2['sum'].sub(df['sum'])

# subtract the delta from the last quarter, obtained
# using filter
# create a placeholder df3
df3=df2.filter(like='Q' ).iloc[:,-1:].sub(df2.iloc[:,-1:].values)
```

I am building from this script, as it does not produce desired result. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Is there an error to (Lower_ stat AA, Q4 27)? The value is 0.6 and the output is 0. It should be 2, no? Same for (Lower_range BB, Q2, 27), the value is 0.4 and the output is 2.

Comment: Hi @Corralien, No there is a condition, it subtracts or adds the delta to match the sum of the nearest even number.

Comment: If the last value is already 0 and you need to subtract 2, can you have negative numbers?

Comment: If last value is 0 it remains 0 @Corralien

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
import numpy as np

# Round the sum to know which rule to apply
arr1 = df.iloc[:, 3:].values
s1 = np.sum(arr1, axis=1)
s1 = np.where(s1 < 0.6, 0, np.ceil(s1 / 2) * 2)

# Do the same but round the array rather than the sum
arr2 = np.where(arr1 < 0.6, 0, np.ceil(arr1 / 2) * 2)
s2 = np.sum(arr2, axis=1)

# Apply the rules
d = s2 - s1  # diff
m = d >= 0  # mask

arr2[m, -1] -= d[m]  # Rule 1: add to the last column
arr2[~m, np.argmax(arr1, axis=1)[~m]] -= d[~m]  # Rule 2: add to the largest column

df.iloc[:, 3:] = arr2
```

Output:

```
>>> df
  location        range role  Q1 27  Q2 27  Q3 27  Q4 27
0       NY   Lower_stat   AA    2.0    2.0    0.0    0.0
1       NY  Lower_range   AA    0.0    2.0    0.0    2.0
2       NY   Lower_stat   BB    0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0
3       NY  Lower_range   BB    0.0    2.0    0.0    0.0
```